# No client side password matching on MVC view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following (abridged) DTO for registering a new user:

```
[PropertiesMustMatch("Password", "ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public class RegisterModel
{
    //.....
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

This is then wrapped in a View Model as such:

```
public class RegisterModelViewData: BaseViewData
{
    public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
    public int PasswordLength { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, on the view, I have the two fields as such:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Password) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Password) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword) %>
</div>
```

Apparently, I am supposed to get a client side validation, and no post, if the passwords don't match.  I get a post and then a message that "Account creation wAs unsuccessful", but nothing about mismatched passwords.  I have omitted the Required and MininumLength attributes from the password proeprties here for brevity, but they seem to behave as expected and validate on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PropertiesMustMatch** is a type validator, not a property validator, and MVC doesn't support client-side validation for type validators, only for property validators.  In his fascinating blog post, [ASP.NET MVC: Adding client-side validation to PropertiesMustMatchAttribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/08/06/asp-net-mvc-adding-client-side-validation-to-propertiesmustmatchattribute.aspx), Stuart Leeks describes how to implement a **MustMatch** property validator that uses client-side validation and can be used to ensure two properties match, e.g. for password confirmation.

Comment: Ah... so it's an MVC thing. Interesting.

Answer (score 17):

Now available in ASP.MVC 3 in case anyone is still wondering

```
public string Password { get; set; }
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must match")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```